# How + adverbs and adjectives

Tags: adverbs

here I am again.

I do know about **How + adverbs or adjectives** (e.g.: *How tall is he?, how handsome is he?, how deep is the river?..*); however, I'd like to know three little things,

**First:** What is this rule's name? If there is one. (The grammar topic which talks about it);

**Second:** Is "**How + adverbs or adjectives**" always complements of the verb? E.g.: **How deep is the river?** - It is **100 feet deep** - **100 feet deep** is the complement of the verb **Is**, since it's a linking verb; therefore, **How deep**" means = "100 feet deep" which is the complement, so,  is it the complement being placed in the beginning?

Thirdy: Could I say: **Is it how deep**? If not, why? What rule talks about placing the adverb in the beginning of the sentence?

Comment: 'How awesome is it / that [?]' can hardly be anything but rhetorical, synonymous with 'It's awesome!'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -  Although this isn't what my question is focused on, I will change this example

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on English determiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners) addresses your first question. / '100 feet deep' is a measure phrase + adjective; these are discussed at _Measure phrases as modifiers of adjectives - Recherches ...
https://rlv.revues.org/pdf/1401
by R Schwarzschild_. Here, they are indeed complements. / Only in a very marked way for emphasis. You can call this the 'start with the wh-word rule' (but I wouldn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these sentences (*How tall is he?, how handsome is he?, how deep is the river?*) are example of interrogative sentences. The word order is: how (question word) + adv/adj + **verb + subject**. These same sentences can be made exclamatory sentences by changing the pattern: how + adv/adj + **subject + verb**.

The verb **'is'**( verb **be** ) is a linking verb and the adjectives 'tall', 'handsome' and 'deep' are subject complements. There are no verb complements,  so there are no adverbs here.

'*How deep is the river?*' - 'It (the river) *is 100 feet deep*'. The phrase '100 feet' modifies the adjective 'deep' and thus becomes an adverbial. But still the phrase '100 feet deep' complements the subject 'the river'.

"*Is it how deep?*" is meaningless and grammatically wrong. It should be either **Is it deep?** or **How deep is it?**, if an interrogative sentence is intended; or, **How deep it is!**, if an exclamation sentence is intended.

Comment: So, the main rule for interrogative adverbs is: They always come in the beginning of the sentence, right?

Comment: @Haseo No: "I didn't know how tall he was". They are *usually* - but not always - fronted to the beginning of the clause NOT the sentence.

Comment: @Araucaria - But in your example, **how tall he was** is a noun clause, not an interrogative wh-question.

How tall he was doesn't matter - Noun Clause
How tall was he? - Interrogative WH-Question

Comment: @Haseo That's the problem if you use terms like "noun clause". If you believe in such things then you need to know that so-called "noun clauses" can be declarative clauses, interrogative clauses, exclamative clauses and so forth. In your particular case your question is about interrogative clauses. In just about every grammar of English "how tall he was" is an interrogative clause in my example (when not given an exclamative interpretation).

Comment: @Araucaria - I do believe in "noun clauses" since it is listed in the main gramamr rules of clauses. There is a very simple way to differ interrogative adverbs from noun clauses:

Noun clauses always take the normal construction: **Adverb + Subject + Predicate**, whereas Interrogative wh-questions are always phrased in the question construction: **Adverb + Verb + Subject + Predicate**. Also, noun clauses can only be used with transitive verbs.

Comment: @Haseo In any grammar that recognises 'noun clauses' (and there aren't many still being followed), noun clauses being CLAUSES have to be one of several different TYPES OF CLAUSE: declarative, closed interrogative, open interrogative, and exclamative. In the case of this 'noun CLAUSE', the clause is interrogative.

Comment: @Haseo "Noun clauses always take the normal construction: Adverb + Subject + Predicate," <-- I have no idea what you're talking about there.

Comment: @Interrogative "wh-questions are always phrased in the question construction: Adverb + Verb + Subject + Predicate" <--I have no idea what you're talking about there either.

Comment: @Araucaria - Nevermind, if I were to explain to you all noun clauses and constructions, I would take a while; therefore, you'd better look it up on google. **mahmud koya** has made my question clear, thank you for your time.